# Jquery UI Multicolumn autocomplete dropdown disappears on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery ui autocomplete as a [multi column autocomplete](http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/g4stL). The code is following

```
 this.$('[data-sandbar="searchbox"]').mcautocomplete({
                showHeader: true,
                columns: [{
                    name: 'First Name',
                    width: '70px',
                    valueField: 'value'
                },
                       {
                           name: 'Last Name',
                           width: '70px',
                           valueField: 'LastName'
                       },
                       {
                           name: 'DOB',
                           width: '50px',
                           valueField: 'DOB'
                       }],


                select: function (event, ui) {
                    window.location.hash = ui.item.name;
                    return false;
                },
                minLength: -1,
                pageSize: 50,
                autoFocus: false,
                source: function (request, response) {

                    self.model.fetch({
                        data: {
                            searchText: text,
                            sortBy: '',
                            pageNum: 1,
                            pageSize: 50,
                            bHotList: false,
                            sortOrder: 'Desc',
                            patientId: 0,
                            include_entities: true
                        },

                        success: function (data) {
                            var availableTags = [];
                            $.each(data.attributes, function (val, patient) {

                                if (patient != "" && patient != null) {

                                    availableTags[val] = {
                                        name: "#patient/" + patient.PatientId,
                                        value: patient.FirstName,
                                        LastName: patient.LastName,
                                        DOB: patient.DOB

                                    };

                                }
                            });

                            response(availableTags);

                        },



                        error: function (e) {
                            console.log(e);

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

I am facing the thing is when I hover the mouse on autocomplete dropdown, mouse hover change the list display block to none. please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be a hover event is register on the autocomplete multiselect combo which cause the change into display property of the list.

thanks.